# Issue, transfer SOL via CPI call

Tags: pda, cpi, transfer, sol, error

I am trying to make a SOL transfer via a CPI call, I managed to create an account to which I have to transfer, this account's authority is owned by a (master) PDA, transfer/deposit works fine but when I try to transfer/withdraw the sol a user (a pubkey) from the CPI call it doesn't work and I get, I believe the signer PDA has the right authorization, correct me I am wrong

`Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Program failed to complete`

My structs look like this
[image]

My withdraw instruction look like this
[image]

and my CPI code look like this
[image]

To call the test I simply call it like that
    `const wtx = await escrowMasterProgram.methods .pullStrings(new BN(lamportz), playerOne.publicKey) .accounts({ puppetProgram: program.programId, puppet: puppetKeypair.publicKey, authority: puppetMasterPDA, }).rpc()`

Can someone please explain what went wrong in my code please?

Comment: please replace all of these screenshots with code blocks

Comment: put the transaction inside try and catch block in client side and console out the error. You would get more information which would help solve the issue. You could also share the error logs so we could help.

Comment: I console.logged the error and got a 

`SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction `

Answer (score 3):

Your `struct PullStrings<'info>` needs to list the `receiver` ("to" account).

Then, in the code for `pull_strings`, you need to add the `receiver` account to the CPI call, calling `set_data`. Then in the code for `set_data`, you need to add `ctx.receiver...` in the `invoke_signed`.

That way, the `receiver` account will be passed in from the client (you can add any Pubkey in the test client), and that receiver account will then be passed down, level by level, until you can use it in the `invoke_signed` of the `transfer_instruction`.

Comment: So I added in `struct PullStrings<'info>` a field `pub to: AccountInfo<'info>` but I get stuck with trying to add the receiver (sorry I am quite new to Rust), so should it be like

`    pub fn pull_strings(ctx: Context<PullStrings>, lamportz: u64) -> Result<()> {
        rps_project::cpi::set_data(ctx.accounts.set_data_ctx()
            .with_signer(&[&[
                b"escrow_wallet".as_ref(), 
                ctx.accounts.puppet.to_account_info().key.as_ref(),
                ]])
            , lamportz, ctx.accounts.to.to_account_info().key) 
    }` ? I removed to:Pubkey from args

Comment: So I also added a pub to: AccountInfo<'info> in the SetData struct https://snipboard.io/I4RLQJ.jpg , then I followed your instructions for next screen https://snipboard.io/fD160t.jpg https://snipboard.io/5gIEFl.jpg but somehow I still get 
`     Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Program failed to complete`

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the "to" account in your SetData account context because your changing its' balance.

Comment: If I add a "to" accountInfo in my SetData struct, how do I pass on the "to" argument accountinfo in my CPI code? Because it takes a pubkey as argument

Comment: Try call to.key if to is of type accountinfo.

Answer (score 0):

Your `from` account is a PDA, and it is not owned by the system program. This is going to sound weird, but that means you cannot use the "transfer" function.

Use `try_mut_borrow_lamports`:

```
ctx.accounts.from.to_account_info().try_borrow_mut_lamports()?.checked_sub(123)
ctx.accounts.to.to_account_info().try_borrow_mut_lamports()?.checked_add(123)
```

##### The Three Rules to Transferring Lamports

Say you want to move lamports *out* of Account A.

1. If `SystemProgram` doesn’t own account A, then you can’t put it in the `from` field of `SystemProgram::transfer`.
2. If *your program* owns account A, then you can use `try_mut_borrow_lamports`.
3. If *some foreign program* owns account A, then you must rely on that program exposing a means of moving lamports out of account A.